# Powershell: how to pass filter value to gci

Tags: powershell

I've got files that matches M*,S* in a folder:

```
PS E:\Uploader> dir M*,S*
    Directory: E:\Uploader
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-----         6/05/2013  10:43 AM    5046659 M_1813O.zip
-a---        26/04/2013   4:51 PM        233 SurveyUploader.config
-a---         8/05/2013   5:15 PM      11788 SurveyUploader.log
-a---         8/05/2013   5:15 PM       6078 SurveyUploader.ps1
-----         6/05/2013  10:43 AM    3473113 S_1813O.zip
```

I simply want to pass this filter to gci in a variable, but it doesn't work:

```
PS E:\Uploader> $k="M*,S*"
PS E:\Uploader> gci *.* -include $k | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}
PS E:\Uploader> gci *.* -include @($k) | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}
<<no files returned!>>
```

If I don't save the filter in a variable, it works fine:

```
PS E:\Uploader> gci *.* -include S*,M* | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}
    Directory: E:\temp\SurveyLoadingAutomation\Uploader
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-----         6/05/2013  10:43 AM    5046659 M_1813O.zip
-a---        26/04/2013   4:51 PM        233 SurveyUploader.config
-a---         8/05/2013   5:15 PM      11788 SurveyUploader.log
-a---         8/05/2013   5:15 PM       6078 SurveyUploader.ps1
-----         6/05/2013  10:43 AM    3473113 S_1813O.zip
```

But I need to pass the filter in a variable in a script.

Any idea?

Comment: In the variable you are specifying a single string (or search term) that happens to have a comma in the middle.  In the no variable case, PowerShell's parser interprets the non-embedded comma as an array operator and constructs an array for you.  Try this `gci * -include "M*,S8"`.  You should see this not work as well and it is the equivalent of what you have in `$k`.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
$k=  @("M*","S*")
```

the `-include` parameter accept `[string[]]` (an array of `string` type )

Comment: Note that the `@()` is not required in this case.  `$k = 'm*','s*'` would suffice to create an array of strings in `$k`.

Comment: Yes true! It's my habit always declare array in this way, just for an easy reading code.